# Calculate the active power

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic and input waveform]

I'm asked to determine the active power (P). (I don't know if that is actually called active power in English?)

The formula of P is = U * I * sin(alpha)

How can we determine the alpha in this case, so that we can calculate the P?

Comment: It's called "active" or "real" power in English, indeed! However, your two diagrams seem to have nothing to do which other (and if I was grading the right plot: no points, since the description what this actually depicts is missing). However, assuming something in your system is not a sinusoidal signal, there's no single "phase" alpha that you could just plug into your formula – it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWV0Um.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input voltage is given in the following diagram:

[image]

Assuming an ideal diode, the negative parts are cut of for the voltage across the resistor. That is shown in the following diagram:

[image]

Now, we know that the power in a resistor is given by:

$$\text{P}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\frac{\text{V}_\text{R}^2\left(t\right)}{\text{R}}\tag1$$

It is not hard to show that \$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\$, is given by:

$$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\frac{\text{V}}{\text{T}}\sum_{\text{n}\ge0}\theta\left(t-\text{Tn}\right)\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(t,\text{T}\right)\tag2$$

Where:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(t,\text{T}\right)=\left(\text{T}\left(1+2\text{n}\right)-2t\right)\left(\theta\left(t-\text{T}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\text{n}\right)\right)+\theta\left(t-\text{T}\left(1+\text{n}\right)\right)\right)\tag3$$

Now, we can look at the average power and the RMS power using the following two formulas:

- Average power:
  $$\overline{\text{P}}_{\text{R}}=\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int_0^\text{T}\text{P}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\tag4$$
- RMS-power:
  $$\text{P}_{\text{R}|\text{RMS}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int_0^\text{T}\text{P}_\text{R}^2\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t}\tag5$$

I used Mathematica to find them:

Average power:

```
In[1]:=Integrate[(1/
    T)*(((Sum[(V/
           T)*((HeavisideTheta[
             t - T*n])*(((-2 t + T + 
               2 n T) (-HeavisideTheta[t - T/2 - n T] + 
               HeavisideTheta[t - (1 + n) T]))/1)), {n, 0, 
         Infinity}])^2)/R), {t, 0, T}, Assumptions -> T > 0]

Out[1]=V^2/(6 R)
```

RMS-power:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Sqrt[(1/T)*
   Integrate[((((Sum[(V/
               T)*((HeavisideTheta[
                 t - T*n])*(((-2 t + T + 
                   2 n T) (-HeavisideTheta[t - T/2 - n T] + 
                   HeavisideTheta[t - (1 + n) T]))/1)), {n, 0, 
             Infinity}])^2)/R))^2, {t, 0, T}, Assumptions -> T > 0]], 
 Assumptions -> V > 0 && R > 0]

Out[2]=V^2/(Sqrt[10] R)
```

Comment: I can't do much about isolated downvoting, the only thing that I can do is vote myself, but that is something that the community can do, so if you see bad votes make sure you also cast a vote ( which the only one that has is me attm)

Comment: No such meaningful quantity as RMS power.

Answer (score 3):

You'll notice that your circuit is nonlinear, due to the diode. Hence, if you want to know powers, you'll have to integrate the squared product of current and voltage over a period and then divide the thus calculated energy by the length of the period.

You seem to have a description of the voltage over time (although that graph isn't sufficiently labeled, so we don't know what we're looking at exactly; this might be the voltage over the diode, over the resistor, or over the voltage source), but you don't have a description of the current. You need to first find that definition of the current over time!

That might be *very* easy, or relatively complex, depending on how *you* model that diode. But it's something we can't do for you.

The rest should just be solving an integral. That's doable.

Answer (score 2):

> *I'm asked to determine the active power (P)*

And

> *The formula of P is = U * I * sin(alpha)*

---

Not in this universe. That formula is for "so-called" *reactive power* but, you don't have any reactive components so it's null and void.

---

The RMS of a triangle or saw-tooth waveform is this: -

[image]

So, without the diode half wave rectifier, the power is: -

$$\dfrac{\left[\dfrac{V_P}{\sqrt3}\right]^2}{R}$$

But, because of the rectifier, only half of that power reaches the load: -

$$\dfrac{\left[\dfrac{V_P}{\sqrt3}\right]^2}{2\cdot R}$$

I'll leave you to plug in the numbers.